# Figure placement Quarto markdown (float specifier)

Tags: pdf, latex, quarto

In LaTeX, it is possible to control figure placement using float specifiers. For example, [H] places the float at precisely the location in the code.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Caption}
\label{label}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figure.png}
\end{figure}
```

How can I do this in Quarto markdown PDF documents if I am including a figure with `![Caption](Figure.png)`?

Answer (score 4):

Use `fig-pos: H` in the YAML header.

```
---
title: Float Specifier
format:
  pdf:
    fig-pos: H
---
 
## Markdown Image

![A black cute dog](dog.jpg)
```

Comment: This specifies it for all images. How can I specify it for each image separately?

Comment: checkout the answer by @A. Bohyn

Answer (score 4):

To complete on [the previous' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76139403/7173666), you can specify the position for a single figure using:

```
![A black cute dog](dog.jpg){fig-pos='H'}
```